# Reference tables dynamically in MySQL / Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, codeigniter

Here is the usecase my team is stuck with:
There are different types of objects in the system, (ex: user, photo, link, video, tag, phototag, etc). Now each object has its own table. When looking up objects for any purpose (say live feed, activity tracking, tagging different object types, etc) ideally the system needs to know three things:
1) The object ID
2) The object type
3) Object details from the object's depending on the usecase

For 1 & 2, i am handling it by adding two columns: object_id, object_type - this will always tell me the ID and what object the Id is referring to. But for step 3 the problem is to get object details I need to know which tables each object relates to. So how do i do that? I am using MySQL and codeignitor php.

One way i can think of is to have a table that has a relation between object and the schema tables. But the downside is then i have to always join this to get the table name then lookup that table. I am hoping to skip any join. Is there anything that can be done within codeignitor for this or any application logic to add which can detect which table to reference based on object type dynamically? And maybe i dont even need the object_Type column and the system can find the table on its own just from the object_id and the page_id or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about `[polymorphic associations][1]` which Rails currently supports. I don't think Codeigniter supports this `by default` (use another layer[ORM]). However, the only thing I can think of is having a library handle this but this will all be conditional statements (ifs).